# Drop Down menu Display using css

Tags: css

In the below image my drop down menu is not displaying over the content.It is very transparent know.Can anyone help me what I have to add to make this drop down menu un-transparent.

[image]

Comment: Looks more like a 'z-index' issue, not transparency

Comment: Maybe we'd be able to if you provided some kind of detail, any kind at all. The relevant CSS and HTML, preferably.

Comment: It's just a picture - we need the code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dropdown is probably a `div` in the html dom. You could find the name of that `div' and then apply a background to it using css:

```
.dropdown_div_name { background-color: white; }
```

#### Edit:

Re looking at the image you posted it is most probably a problem with the `z-index` as others also suggested, since for example if you look at the 'Technology/Connected TV' header, that shows over the menu contents. That could be fixed by changing the `z-index` of the dropdown menu

```
.dropdown_div_name { z-index:100; }
```

where `100` should be a number bigger than the `z-index` of the rest items that you want it to overlap

Answer (score 0):

A `background-color`. Without one, the default colour is `transparent`, hence you see everything behind it.